# Sum different items in two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to have two columns that show the sum of different items purchased. For example

**DB Name: Purchases**

| CustomerID | Shirt |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Red |
| 123 | Red |
| 123 | Red |
| 123 | Blue |
| 123 | Blue |

The result I'd like to get is the following

| CustomerID | Red | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | 2 |

I am able to create one column but I am having difficulty creating two different columns.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  This is particularly simple in MySQL:

```
select customerid,
       sum(shirt = 'Red') as red,
       sum(shirt = 'Blue') as blue
from t
group by customerid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9fc05969e5cce05f962b61534ef51579) is a db<>fiddle.

The above uses a MySQL shortcut.  The general syntax uses `case`:

```
select customerid,
       sum(case when shirt = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as red,
       sum(case when shirt = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue
from t
group by customerid;
```

Comment: Ok, that's what a tried but it's telling me that there is an incorrect syntax near ')'  but my code is identical to yours.

Comment: @irishninja002 . . . I added a db<>fiddle with that *exact* code and it works fine.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff I was using Microsoft SQL server. The expanded query worked actually.

Comment: @irishninja002 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I'm sorry if I did - this is only my second time on Stackoverflow. what you provided was very helpful. I thought I clicked the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should complete the sum statement with that :

```
select customerid,
   sum(case when shirt = 'Red' Then 1 Else 0 End) as red,
   sum(case when shirt = 'Blue' Then 1 Else 0 End) as blue
from t
group by customerid;
```